# Как получить значения data атрибутов в slick?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как получить data и записать их в slick dots, почему undefined?
https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/vVzpNW

```
$(".slider").slick({
dots: true,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,

    //autoplay: true,
    //dots: true
    customPaging : function(slider, i) {
        var title = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('title');
        return '<a class="pager__item"> '+title+' </a>';
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда появляются такие проблемы советую пользоваться инспектором (Chrome - F12).

Как мы можем наблюдать, этот плагин генерит дополнительную обертку в виде двух дивов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому `slider.$slides[i]` возвращает `div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active"` элемент вместо интересующего вас элемента.

Решение в лоб - взять внука этого слайда:

```
var title = $(slider.$slides[i].children[0].children[0]).data("title");
```